# SpiceService with per-request network state checker

Tags: android, robospice

RoboSpice service can be configured to be used offline ([SampleOfflineSpiceService](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/blob/release/robospice-sample-core-offline/src/com/octo/android/robospice/sample/offline/SampleOfflineSpiceService.java)).

1. Is it possible to achieve a per-request checking if network is required? E.g. `LoadDataFromFileRequest` don't use network, so network checking should be skipped for these request. All other requests should check for network.
2. Is it recommended to have 2 implementation of `SpiceService` just for this?

Answer (score 3):

that's a good question no one came up earlier with.

I would say that you need 2 Robospice services to achieve this. The service that won't use default shared NetworkStateChecker should be a custom service.

I think latest release increased the ability to plug on different hooks and will ease this, but I am not sure you can actually really achieve it in current state of RS.

Please, open an issue on GitHub if this doesn't work. We also greatly appreciate pull requests.

Comment: Thanks. I skimmed through the latest sources and also think that it can't be done yet. I'll take a look soon.

Comment: Go for a PR then, we would be glad to help.

Comment: @Snicolas, is newest version of RoboSpice allow it? I mean setting custom NetworkStateChecker for different request?